# Express not passing req.params when using a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a convention-based router for Express that handles parameters.

All is working pretty good, however, when I load a route, req.params is empty.

I resorted to pass req.params in req.vars to have the router working.

Is there a better method? I would like to have the routes working as close to vanilla Express as possible.

Here is the router:

```js
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

const router  = express.Router();

//path of the routes
const routesPath = './routes'

//function to generate the list of routes
const routes = (dir, filelist = [], firstDir = null) => {
    firstDir = firstDir||dir;
    fs.readdirSync(dir).forEach(file => {

        filelist = fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory()
        ? routes(path.join(dir, file), filelist, firstDir)
        : filelist.concat(path.relative(firstDir, path.join(dir, file)));

    });
    return filelist;
}

//Read each file in the routesPath directory
routes(path.join(__dirname, routesPath))
    //sort by parameter position (square brackets) to avoid conflicts with other routes
    .sort((a, b)=>{
        let pathValueReducer = (sum, cur, idx) => {
            //a reducer that gives a numerical value to the folder based on square brackets position
            if (cur.match(/^\[.*?\]$/m))
                //increase if there is a param
                cur=1;
            else
                //decrease if it's absent (only 0.5 to avoid conflicts) 
                //NOT VERY SURE ABOUT THIS MAYBE IT SHOULD BE Much LESS OR EVEN 0 no conflict found untill now
                cur=-0.5;
            //multiply by power of 0.1 to index to avoid conflicts
            cur *= Math.pow(0.1, idx);
            return sum + cur;
        }

        //regex to match slashes and dots
        let splitRegEx = /[\\\/\.]/;

        //add a 0 or it will break not shure why
        let valA = [0, ...a.split(splitRegEx)].reduce((sum, cur, idx) => pathValueReducer(sum, cur, idx));
        let valB = [0, ...b.split(splitRegEx)].reduce((sum, cur, idx) => pathValueReducer(sum, cur, idx));

        return valA-valB;
    })
    .forEach((route)=>{
        // Strip the .js suffix and split by slashes (both to then replace them and to match params in square brackets)
        route = route.split('.')[0].split(/[\\\/]/);

        //create file path
        let filepath=(routesPath+'/' + route.join('/') + '.js');

        //create route url
        let url = '/' + route
            .map( dir => {
                if (dir.match(/^\[.*?\]$/m))
                    dir = ':' + dir.substr(1).slice(0, -1);
                return dir;
            })
            //Remove index files and mount as father dir. Also removes empty items just to be safe
            .filter(dir => dir!=='index' && dir != '')
            .join('/');

        //Here it states what it is trying to do
        console.log(
            '\x1b[36m' + '[router] Trying to load file',
            '\x1b[35m' + filepath, 
            '\x1b[36m' + 'on route', 
            '\x1b[35m' + url
        );

        //mount the route
        try{
            //pass params to vars since req.params don't work
            router.use(url, function(req, res, next) {req.vars={...req.params}; next();}, require(filepath).default || require(filepath));
            //success message
            console.log('\x1b[32m' +'Loaded');
        }catch(err){
            //fail message
            console.log('\x1b[31m' + '[router]', path.join(__dirname, filepath));
            console.log('\x1b[31m' + "The file doesn't have the right extension (only .js allowed) or contains errors:" );
            console.log('\x1b[31m' + err );
        }
    });

export default router;
```

And here is the route .routes/[test].js that gets :test as a parameter:

```js
import express from 'express';

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //what I use
  res.json({
    id: 1,
    thisIsATest: req.vars.test
  });
  //what I would like to use
  res.json({
    id: 1,
    thisIsATest: req.params.test
  });
});

export default router;
```

Comment: change '/' route to '/:test' and access req.params.test by passing /testdata(eg) like this

Comment: If I then have to do the routing manually in each route file wouldn't that defy the purpose of having the automatic router set up like that?

Comment: Right now the file ./routes/[test]/something/[test2].js would respond correctly if I go to /asdf/something/qwer and I would find the params test and test2 in req.vars.test and req.vars.test2. All this without modifying the route in the route file. I would just like to have req.vars in req.params as default for Express.